# CATransition white flash in background?

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller, catransition

I'm trying to make a pushViewController slide in from the left, not the right, as follows:

```
Page14Controller * controller = [[Page14Controller alloc] initWithNibName:@"Page14Controller" bundle:nil];

CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = 0.3;
transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
//                transition.type = kCATransitionMoveIn; 
transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
//kCATransitionMoveIn; //, kCATransitionPush, kCATransitionReveal, kCATransitionFade
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft; 
//kCATransitionFromLeft, kCATransitionFromRight, kCATransitionFromTop, kCATransitionFromBottom
[self.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:NO];
```

When I do this, the current controller fades to white, which looks terrible. Why does this happen? I've tried setting the background of the current view's alpha to 0.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured out what was apparently causing the white flash: it was the background of the main window. Setting this to alpha=0 helps the white effect. It [appears that kCATransitionPush actually fades the view being pushed off screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505413/iphone-how-to-do-kcatransitionpush-without-any-fade), and obviously if what is under that is green, then it'll fade to green. It'd be nice if it didn't also fade, but that's a different question.

Comment: TY! I did have a sneaky UIView in between there that was white and that ended up causing that white background "noise".

Comment: Hi, I have exactly the same problem and I tried to set .backgroundColor of my UIWindow with an alpha = 0 but it doesn't solve the problem. What do you do exactly ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'd avoid messing with UIViewController's view too much.

The easier way to achieve what you want is with something like this:

```
UINavigationController * nc = self.navigationController;
NSArray * viewControllers = ;
NSMutableArray * newControllers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[nc viewControllers]];
[newControllers insertObject:controller atIndex:newControllers.count-1];
nc.viewControllers = newControllers;
[nc popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Note that it *replaces* the top view controller with the new controller instead of just pushing it; this may not be what you want (but if you're using it to simulate page-changing, you probably don't want to perpetually push more controllers until you run out of memory).

Comment: I do want to push a new controller, though, as the new controller has a back button which will slide it off to the left, restoring the previous controller.

Comment: If you're going to do lots of custom stuff, then it might be worthwhile doing all the custom transitions yourself. You can just set view.frame, for instance.