# UINavigationController override push from Right to Left showing black background

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller

Does anyone knows why when overriding push or pop to right to left it shows this black faded line behind the push it self?

Image attached that shows the issue:

[image]

This is what I use to push:

```
- (void)pushViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super pushViewController:viewController animated:NO];
    if (animated)
    {
        CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
        transition.duration = TRANSITION_DURATION;
        transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionDefault];
        transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
        transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft;
        [self.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
    }
}
```

This is for pop:

```
- (UIViewController *)popViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{
    if (animated)
    {
        CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
        transition.duration = TRANSITION_DURATION;
        transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionDefault];
        transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
        transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight;
        [self.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
    }
    return [super popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```

Comment: Hey guys, still go no answer here.. please help someone.

Comment: i think it is helpfull for you:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6433385/catransition-white-flash-in-background?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Instead of 
[self.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil]
you should write
[self.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:kCATransition];

Answer (score 0):

I had `"self.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;"` set in some of my **view controllers**. Removing this line fixed the irregular animation and black screen issues.